# Best way to change the innerHTML for an entire class or arrray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

When I run this code it is changing all of the volunteersName and only the first set of the other items. Once it loops it doesn't change the other values. Hopefully someone can help me find my issue. I'm guessing I can't use a loop for this and maybe need to use forEach? Not sure exactly how to do this properly. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm getting this console error below

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
function invite() {
    for (index = 1; index >= volunteersName.length; index++) {
            var names = [document.getElementById("volunteersName" + index).value];
            document.getElementById("name" + index).innerHTML = names
            document.querySelector(".organizationName2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("organizationName").value;
            document.querySelector(".eventDate2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventDate").value;
            document.querySelector(".websiteURL2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("websiteURL").value;
            document.querySelector(".hostName2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("hostName").value;
    }
```

Comment: querySelector of a class returns an array , you can't change the innerHtml of an array, you have to use the index for changing the innerHtml of class.

Comment: You are assigning the `innerHTML` to an array.

Comment: The loop is running as is. When I make the change you said it stops the loop and makes the `name` stop working as well as the other items.

Comment: Yes I am but I'm not sure how to change innerHTML for an array properly without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loop syntax.

```
for (index = 1; index >= volunteersName.length; index++) {
```

This says the loop should run for as long as `index` is **equal to or greater than** the length of your array.

So unless your array has 1 or 0 items in it, it will never run, since `index` starts at 1.

Change to:

```
for (index = 1; index <= volunteersName.length; index++) {
```

...so the loop runs as long as `index` is **equal to or less than** the length of the array.

Comment: Still not working :-/ I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` on the `var names =` line

Comment: Then your DOM doesn't contain the elements you think it does. Specifically, there is no elemtent whose ID matches "volunteersName" + the current value of `index`

Comment: I got it working with the code in my answer but I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure how it is inserting the correct values but I'm getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` still

Comment: I can only repeat :) That error explicitly means that your DOM does not contain an element with the ID you are currently looking for (in the loop). Do feel free to upvote at any time for all the help :-D

Comment: If you can recreate in a Fiddle or Core Pen I'll demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Here is the fiddle and when I upvote it tells me I need 15 rep for the upvote to show lol     https://jsfiddle.net/3y0zLufw/#&togetherjs=RoU3zNFyUA

Comment: Fair play. What should I do in the Fiddle, and what should I expect to happen?

Comment: It's working properly in every way but I'm getting that error in the console

Comment: Maybe easier to look at site page here http://capellavolunteers.epizy.com/invitation.html

Comment: If you enter a number for number of volunteers in first box and the a form will pop up. after filling out the form with any content and press the submit button the content you entered will transfer to the readout below for each volunteer but then the error pops up on the submit button.

Comment: I'm out currently but when I look at the Fiddle and enter a number in the box, nothing happens for me.

Comment: That is very odd, I'm in the fiddle now and the boxes pop up for me

Comment: After looking at the fiddle it looks like it is not recognizing the back-tic for my multi-line innerHTML. It blocks it out as text but I'm not sure it can see the elements inside of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `querySelector` you can use `querySelectorAll` and iterate through index.

```
function invite() {
    for (index = 1; index <= volunteersName.length; index++) {
            var names = [document.getElementById("volunteersName" + index).value];
            document.getElementById("name" + index).innerHTML = names
            document.querySelectorAll(".organizationName2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("organizationName").value;
            document.querySelectorAll(".eventDate2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventDate").value;
            document.querySelectorAll(".websiteURL2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("websiteURL").value;
            document.querySelectorAll(".hostName2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("hostName").value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I got it working properly with the `querySelectorAll` answer but for some reason I need to keep `index >= volunteersName`

This is the code that makes it execute properly below

```
function invite() {
    for (index = 1; index >= volunteersName.length; index++) {
            var names = [document.getElementById("volunteersName" + index).value];
            document.getElementById("name" + index).innerHTML = names
            document.querySelectorAll(".organizationName2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("organizationName").value;
            document.querySelectorAll(".eventDate2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("eventDate").value;
            document.querySelectorAll(".websiteURL2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("websiteURL").value;
            document.querySelectorAll(".hostName2")[index-1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("hostName").value;
    }

}
```